# npm package to build mongo query from URL query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I have the following mongo documents:

```
[{
    "name": "Robert",
    "title": "The art of war",
    "description": "The art of war in the 20yh century"
},
{
    "name": "Claadius",
    "title": "The spring is back",
    "description": "I love spring and all the seasons"
}
]
```

On my GET method, I have a query to perform the search on 1 attribute alone, 2 or 3 together. See example:  `?name=Robert&title=war&description=spring`

How i can implement this?

Comment: there are plenty of npm mongo plugins (see https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongo%20query )  It's unclear exactly what you're looking for, but have a look at the range available before re-inventing the wheel. At a quick glance, maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-to-mongo may work for you? or perhaps mongodb-querystring

Comment: query-to-mongo was the one I have checked, but documentation is not very useful as I am quite starting with node.js.  What I want to do is, for example, to return all the documents with the name containing Robert or name containing Robert AND title containing "war". I have it done using regex expressions, but it starts to get confusing when the number of query parameters increases.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost exactly what query-to-mongo was meant for! It converts a query like the one you show into a mongo search criteria that can be passed into a mongo *find*. It handles a bunch of additional search operators (like >= and !=) which is where it gets complicated.

But if you're willing to trust it, here's an example of an express route that performs a find against a collection using a search query:

https://gist.github.com/pbatey/20d99ff772c29146897834d0f44d1c29

The query-to-mongo parser also handles paging into results with *offset* and *limit*.